# Why are images are classified only in one category

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

I am using VGG16 to classify images into 8 skin lesion types. I am getting only 15% of accuracy for my model and my model is classifying all the images into one class during prediction.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras.models import Sequential
from glob import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# re-size all the images to this
IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224]
TARGET_SIZE = (224,244) 
BATCH_SIZE = 128
EPOCHS = 100

TRAIN_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ISIC_2019/Train/'
VALID_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ISIC_2019/Test/'

label = ['AK', 'BCC','BKL','DF','MEL','NV','SCC','VASC']
counts=[]

def estimate_weights_mfb(label):
  class_weights = np.zeros_like(label, dtype=np.float)
  counts = np.zeros_like(label)
  for i,l in enumerate(label):
    dir_path = os.path.join(TRAIN_PATH,l)
    counts[i] = len(os.listdir(dir_path))
  counts = counts.astype(np.float)
  median_freq = np.median(counts)
  
  for i, label in enumerate(label):
    class_weights[i] = median_freq / counts[i]
  
  return class_weights

cw= estimate_weights_mfb(label)

lesionclassweight={}
for key in range(len(label)):
    lesionclassweight[key]=cw[key]

print(lesionclassweight)

# add preprocessing layer to the front of VGG
base_model = VGG16(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# don't train existing weights
for layer in vgg.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
  
  # useful for getting number of classes
folders = glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/ISIC_2019/Train/*')

# our layers - you can add more if you want
x = Flatten()(base_model.output)
# x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)
prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')(x)

# create a model object
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=prediction)

# view the structure of the model
model.summary()

# tell the model what cost and optimization method to use

model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   rotation_range=90,
                                   brightness_range=[0.1, 0.7],
                                   width_shift_range=0.5, 
                                   height_shift_range=0.5)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_PATH,
                                                 target_size = TARGET_SIZE,
                                                 batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALID_PATH,
                                            target_size = TARGET_SIZE,
                                            batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')


# ModelCheckpoint callback - save best weights
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/content/drive/MyDrive/VGG16_before_fine_tuning.best.hdf5',
                                  monitor='val_accuracy',
                                  save_best_only=True,
                                  verbose=1)

# EarlyStopping
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                           patience=10,
                           restore_best_weights=True,
                           mode='min')
                           
# fit the model
r = model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=EPOCHS,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set),
  callbacks=[model_checkpoint, early_stop],
  verbose=1,
  class_weight=lesionclassweight
)
```

Below is the confusion matrix after predicting on test data.

[image]

PS: Code for confusion not provided above.

As you can see all the images are classified into only one class.

Comment: I think you should add more trainable layers. Since you are loading a VGG model, which is pretrained on imagenet dataset. And then you are freezing all layers, and add just the output layer with 8 neurons. Since your dataset is medical images, its far from imagenet samples, and you can not get desired result with only 8 neurons trained with your images. add some more layers and then test the predictions.

Comment: Can you give some example which would be common to other CNNs as well?

Comment: Simply add some other dense layers, like the line you commented (` x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)`, and see if anything changed.